# How to get diff between utc time and localtime in seconds?

Tags: bash, date

How to get in bash diff between utc time and localtime in seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` isn't trivially part of the answer without some time-related antics, epoch seconds is explicitly UTC (or maybe GMT if you're old-school), so setting TZ won't affect it.

Similar to twalberg's suggestion:

```
IFS=":" read hh mm < <(date +%:z)
echo $(($hh*3600+$mm*60))
```

You can test that this is doing what you want by setting TZ for the `date` command:

```
IFS=":" read hh mm < <(TZ=Australia/Sydney date %:z)    # answer is 39600
IFS=":" read hh mm < <(TZ=US/Eastern date +%:z)         # answer is -18000
```

(This isn't *strictly* a bash answer, since it requires GNU date or equivalent, 5.90 and later support %:z and %::z)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do a little work to get it in seconds, but `date +%z` will report your configured timezone offset as `[+-]HHMM`. Parse the output of that and do the appropriate math to figure it out in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work in places with whole hours and not minutes.

```
echo $(($( date +%z)*36))
```